# Installing unit test generator in visual studio 2013 gives error .net framework is not installed

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

[image]

I was searching about unit testing but I found missing create unit test option on method that was available on vs2010, then I find option to install Unit test Generator extension. This too is not installed. I have also tried to enter  EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.CreateUnitTests in the Command Window, but the Command Prompt said that no such command exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Had to do a little digging, and I wish that Google would take you to the subpage where it matches your search criteria. This guy had the answer that worked for me:

> Written August 31, 2015 woeful
>
> This install continually failed for me on Windows 10 indicating I did
>   not have the required .Net framework installed. I tried closing VS and
>   installing the vsix file by directly executing the downloaded file,
>   but this still failed.
>
> I eventually got this to work by installing the VS 2013 Update 5
>   package. Then I was able to install the vsix file without any further
>   errors.

After I let the package install, I was able to install the Unit Test Generator off the Tools->Extensions and Updates menu. Hope this solves your problem. Although, you probably should make sure you also have MSTest and NUnit installed just to on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks you replyed me.. but i Moved to vs 2015 which already have unit test option